# Displaying javascript calculated variable output as currency

Tags: javascript, jquery, shopify

I currently have a variable that is made up of two calculated variables. How ever I need to display the outputted variable as a currency which includes thousand separators.

In this instance, the user inputs the width and length of a room and then the java calculates and tells the user how much the required quantity will be. I will add my code below to help see how this is currently working.

All help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Here is the calculation variable:

```
$price = ($quantity_needed*pricePerTile);
$('#ft-price-res').text("£"+$price.toFixed(3));
```

The full javascript for this page you can view here: https://jsfiddle.net/3yw4m7kj/

Comment: Does [`Intl.NumberFormat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat/NumberFormat) meet your needs?

Answer (score 0):

e.g.:

```js
$('#ft-price-res').text(Intl.NumberFormat('en-GB', {
   style:'currency', 
   currency:'GBP', 
   minimumFractionDigits:3
}).format($price));
```

and fairly safe to use : https://caniuse.com/?search=Intl.NumberFormat

Comment: Hi, it formatted the number but not quite how it should. Instead of formatting as a number in the hundres it formatted the number in the thousands. 

for example the outputted number was 18028, and instead of formatting as £180.20, it formatted as £18,028.00. Hope this makes sense and any help is appreciated!

Comment: The example was based on your code. If your number is in pence(?) then you’d have to convert to lb ` /100 ` and set the fraction digits to 2